# Avoid double slashes from json string json-c

Tags: c, json, glib, json-c

I tried to encode a byte array using glib2.0. After I add the encoded data to a `json` object, after I send the encoded data through `pubnub` client, 
 I got doble slashed string from json.

This is my code :

```
//code for encoding data

const guchar *data=inputEncodingData;
encodedData=g_base64_encode (data,datalength);  
g_print("Encoded data==>%s\n",encodedData);
```

It produces encoded string with slashes. like this

```
KA4IChkAGQAAAAAAAAAAAOAO4A4uDgAAAAAAAAoAGAAmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQD//wAAwf/A/8D/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEA//8CAP7/BAD6/wgA9P8SAOb/JwA2/A39mP0AAAIA4P/wD939pf2w/eL87vxz
/Nn7zasAAHMKAADIlAkKGAAYAAAAAAAAAAAA4Jbgls6UAAAAAAAACgAYACYAAAAAAAAAyf+9/7//
vv/B/8D/wP+8/77/v//C/8D/vf+//8D/wP++/77/
```

This is the code for creating json object:

```
struct json_object *obj1;
obj1 = json_object_new_object();    
json_object_object_add(obj1, "result", json_object_new_string(encodedData));
```

This will print like this:

```
KA4IChkAGQAAAAAAAAAAAOAO4A4uDgAAAAAAAAoAGAAmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQD\/\/wAAwf\/A\/8D\/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEA\/\/8CAP7\/BAD6\/wgA9P8SAOb\/JwA2\/A39mP0AAAIA4P\/wD939
pf2w\/eL87vxz\/Nn7zasAAHMKAADIlAkKGAAYAAAAAAAAAAAA4Jbgls6UAAAAAAAACgAYACYAAA
AAAAAAyf+9\/7\/\/vv\/B\/8D\/wP+8\/77\/v\/\/C\/8D\/vf+\/\/8D\/wP++\/77\/
```

Why is it like this? Any idea? I need data with one slash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json-c string with "/" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588310/json-c-string-with-character)